# SFDX problem: ERROR running force:limits:api:display: limits resource is not enabled

Tags: salesforcedx, limits, scratch-org

Whilst there have been previous queries along these lines (including [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28037/messagelimits-resource-is-not-enabled-errorcodeapi-disabled-for-org)) the answers don't appear to be valid as of the Spring '20 Lightning Platform.

I am trying to allow the developers using SFDX to be able to execute the command:

```
sfdx force:limits:api:display -u <dev hub user>
```

We are a Partner and therefore have our Dev Hub on our Partner Business Org, where we have limited access user accounts for our developers just so they can use SFDX.

Whilst this used to work when we first migrated to SFDX about 10 months ago it has stopped working in the more recent past. At first I thought it was something our PBO admin had done, but apparently not.

In searching for the solution I found the [cited question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28037/messagelimits-resource-is-not-enabled-errorcodeapi-disabled-for-org), above, and tried to follow those instructions, which are to ensure the developers have two specific system permissions enabled.

When I configure the "free limited access license" permission set for our developers on our Dev Hub org (PBO as mentioned above and as per Salesforce directions) I can ensure that I select the "API Enabled" system permission, but the "View Setup and Configuration" is not listed in the permission set's System Permissions page. Having just this one permission doesn't resolve the issue.

**EDIT**: I also checked the "Limited Access User" profile in use, and this already had "API Enabled" set true in the "Administrative Permissions" section, which also doesn't include the "View Setup and Configuration" option.

Has Salesforce broken this feature for PBO usage in the latest release(s)?

Comment: I was able to run this SFDX command against my developer org. Are you unable to run this command even as an admin?

Comment: Our Dev Hub is not a developer org - it is our Partner Business Org. Our developers are not admins on this org so cannot rely on having admin rights. As I said, this used to work but now doesn't with no changes to the configuration for our Dev Hub and our dev hub users' profile and permission set.